# Python declare variables only the first time I call a function

Tags: python

I have a function in python and I want to declare 2 variables only the first time I call this function and then change their values, something like this :

```
def function():
  x=0
  z=2
  if(x>z):
    other_function()
  else:
    x+=1
```

With this way,every time I call the `function()`, x becomes 0 and z becomes 2.

I tried to make them global outside of the function() but it gives me error :

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

How can I declare the values the first time I call the function()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with the other answers, that only try to give a direct answer to your question.

You have a combination of *state* (the variables) with *a function / functions using that state*. That's what a **class** is for.

```
class myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.z = 2

    def myfunction(self):
        if self.x > self.z:
            other_function()  # Possibly self.other_function()
                              # if that one also uses x or z
        else:
            self.x += 1
```

Use as:

```
instance = myclass()
instance.myfunction()
instance.myfunction()  # Etc
```

Comment: that worked!thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of lexical scope and global in Python:

```
x = 0
z = 2
def foo():
    global x
    if (x > z):
        bar()
    else:
        x += 1
foo()
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))

You should write some like this:

```
 
def f(x):
    def g(y):
        return x + y
    return g
```

def h(x):
    return lambda y: x + y

a = f(1)
b = h(1)
f(1)(5)
h(1)(5)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get x and z from somewhere outside of the function then they'll have to be passed to `function` as arguments. For example:

```
def function(a,b):
    if(a>b):
        other_function()
    else:
        a+=1

    return a, b
```

which can then be called with

```
x, z = function(0,2)
```

Comment: this will not work unfortunately because a will be local, so `a+=1` won't work. Yet your thinking is good.

Comment: ah, quite right. I'll edit to reflect

Answer (score 0):

You could use default function arguments

**i.e.)**

```
def function(x = None, z = None):
   if x is None:
        x=0
   if z is None:
        z=2
```

If you pass the value of `x or z the passed value is used else it is initialized to the value given in the function`

Answer (score 0):

You can abuse the mighty mutable default value **with caution**.

```
def func(vals = {'x': 0, 'z': 2}):
    print vals['x']
    vals['x'] += 1

func()
>> 0
func()
>> 1
func()
>> 2
```

Although I guess the **proper** way of doing this will be using a decorator:

```
def default_value_decorator(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        returned_val = func(*args, **kwargs)
        inner.x += 1
        return returned_val
    inner.x = 0
    inner.z = 2
    return inner

@default_value_decorator
def func():
    print func.x

func()
>> 0
func()
>> 1
```

And a more reusable version where the starting values of `x` and `z` can be passed to the decorator:

```
def default_value_decorator(x, z):
    def a(func):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            returned_val = func(*args, **kwargs)
            inner.x += 1
            return returned_val
        inner.x = x
        inner.z = z
        return inner
    return a

@default_value_decorator(0, 2)
def func():
    print func.x

func()
>> 0
func()
>> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put them in a dictionary for better readability:

```
_VALS = {'x': 0, 'z': 2}
def function():
  if _VALS['x'] > _VALS['z']:
    other_function()
  else:
     _VALS['x'] += 1
```